# How to fix debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog error w/Packer?

Tags: apt, software-installation, error-handling, automation, debconf

I am using the [Packer](https://www.packer.io) [`vsphere-iso` builder](https://www.packer.io/plugins/builders/vsphere/vsphere-iso) to build an Ubuntu-18.04 VM on vSphere with [a `shell` provisioner](https://www.packer.io/docs/provisioners/shell), and when I run either of the following two commands:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common --yes
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates curl gnupg lsb-release --yes
```

I get these errors below:

```
==> vsphere-iso.ubuntu-18_04-base-template: debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
==> vsphere-iso.ubuntu-18_04-base-template: debconf: (Dialog frontend will not work on a dumb terminal, an emacs shell buffer, or without a controlling terminal.)
==> vsphere-iso.ubuntu-18_04-base-template: debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
==> vsphere-iso.ubuntu-18_04-base-template: debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
==> vsphere-iso.ubuntu-18_04-base-template: debconf: (Can't locate Term/ReadLine.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Term::ReadLine module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.26.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.26.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.26 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.26 /usr/share/perl/5.26 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Readline.pm line 7, <> line 31.)
==> vsphere-iso.ubuntu-18_04-base-template: debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
==> vsphere-iso.ubuntu-18_04-base-template: dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin:
```

Googling for this issue I find many who say that setting `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` fixes the issue, including here on Ask Ubuntu, however that has not fixed the issue for me.

I know I can pipe errors to `/dev/null` but I'd rather not do that in case errors that break the build happen. I'd like to actually stop the error from occurring, such as setting `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` to `noninteractive` was supposed to do.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74725280/1110820) says:

```
echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections
```

Additionally, [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34773745/debconf-unable-to-initialize-frontend-dialog#comment132773588_74725280) adds:

> I'd recommend to run debconf-show debconf to see the default so that it helps to restore the default, if something happens while executing the above.